# Touchpad not working on acer travelmater x483 during and after installation of 12.04

Tags: touchpad, acer

I have tried  Fn+F7, that, did not work.  All your responses is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the login prompt, try to hit Fn+F7 first and test if your touchpad works, then you may now login.

If you're already logged-in and didn't hit the Fn+F7 button, you're obliged to use a mouse because the touchpad will not work. I hope there's an update on this one soon.

Comment: TY, log in prompt? Before or after acer sign comes on ? Tell me and i will try it for sure.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  It worked!  Now, i do agree with you RE: UPDATE for this

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT CORRECTION: I have an brand new Acer TravelMate X483-6691 . Linpus's GUI would not launch. Acer support was a joke. So, let's put on Lubuntu! I loaded Lubuntu14. Be sure to change the boot order (F2 when booting) so the CD boots first.

I did the "wife install" of Lubuntu. Blowing out Linpus completely.

Wifi drivers worked like a charm. But the trackpad was DOA after install :-( .  Luckily, a handy Logitech USB mouse worked like a charm. Yea.

The above suggestions were close to address the track pad failure, but not exactly right to get the track pad to work.

Here is how to get the track pad to work.  Boot up, and before or after log in, press the following:

Ctrl+Fn+F7

Bingo! We have ignition, and the track pad works.

The only downside, upon reboot, you must do the Ctrl+Fn+F7 to get the track pad to work.

Oh, and Lubuntu is faster on this machine than Unity-bloat Ubuntu!